# How to add an endscreen?

Tags: python, pygame

I tried different codes from here and other places but I just can't seem to get my end screen to work.

I've tried many times to transition to end screen but either the code fails completely or my sprites appear on top of the end screen. This is what I have right now because it allows my code to run.

```
collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, enemy_list, False)
    if collide:
        run = False
```

I want it to be game over when the enemy sprite touches the player sprite but because of the codes above which makes the enemy sprite follow the player sprite, an error always appears: "float division 0". It's probably just my fault for using the wrong code though.

I'm not sure if the other codes affect the end screen codes but just in case, this is my entire code:

```
Code is removed for now. Will re-upload in 1 to 2 months
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `gameover` state to the program and set the state when the player collides.

Create a separate function for the game over screen. The `gameover` function has its own event loop:

```py
def gameOverScreen():
    global run, gameover

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = True

        # do event handling which continues the game
        # [...]
        # if [...]
        #     gameover = False

    # draw the game over screen
    # [...]

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(100)
```

Call this function dependent on the state of `gameover` in the main loop.
Use the [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) stement to contiunue the main loop immediately.

```py
gameover = False
run = True
while run:

    # [...]

    if not gameover and time_difference >= 1500:
        # [...]

    win.fill(white)
    win.blit(background.image, background.rect)

    if not pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
        pygame.mixer.music.load('bgm.mp3')
        pygame.mixer.music.play()

    if gameover:
        gameOverScreen()
        continue # continue main loop

    for e in enemy_list:
        e.move(player)

    collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, enemy_list, False)
    if collide:
        gameover = True

    # [...]
```

Comment: For the `def gameOverScreen():` do I put it in the main loop? Also, what do I put in the event handling? I'm not sure if it's something I did wrong there but it makes my game screen keep flickering. @Rabbid76

Comment: @helpless `gameOverScreen()` is a function put it in global scope. "*What do I put"* - how should I know? How do you want to restart your game (e.g. press a key)? *"it makes my game screen keep flickering"* -  Did you write the `continue` statement? How may `pygame.display.flip()` and `pygame.display.update()`  are in `gameOverScreen()`? There should be only 1.

Comment: Sorry. I should have showed my code to you. I edited my codes in the question. It works now but I'm not sure if it's because I have done something wrongly, the timer continues to run after the game have ended. (To clarify, I put the timer formula code on the end screen because I want a line that says "you survived for x seconds") @rabbid76

Comment: @helpless You can move the timer code a bit downwards in the main loop (after the (`if gameover:`) part or you can do it only `if not gameover and time_difference >= 1500:`